# Boolean equal: 0 == a, does operand order matter?

Tags: java, equals-operator

I saw some people wrote this Boolean equal in their code, I usually put constant at the right hand side of "==" operator. I notice 0 == a has faster operation than a == 0. Can someone explain why? And what's the best practice for it?

Comment: `0 == a` is not faster than `a == 0`, nor the other way around. What makes you think that?

Comment: What you're asking about is called a [Yoda Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) - there is no performance difference, only safety against typos, and it doesn't really apply in Java since you can't accidentally assign *because* it has to be a boolean expression (as long as you don't accidentally assign a boolean in an expression, of course)

Comment: +1 as question is ok though he assumed wrong about performance

Comment: @Jesper it was one simple question on leetcode, the I revised the solution with only changing 0 == a to a == 0, and noticed the run time was a bit longer than before. Sorry for assuming it as a matter of course

Comment: It's an outdated C/C++ thing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a relic of the C/C++ world.

In C, the advantage of writing `0 == a` vs. `a == 0` is that you can't accidentally write `a = 0` instead, which means something entirely different. Since `0` is an rvalue, `0 = a` is illegal.

In Java that reasoning does not apply because `a = 0` is illegal as well (since `0` is not boolean, `a` can't be boolean). It doesn't hurt though, so it really doesn't matter a lot which one to choose.

Performance has absolutely nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers have described, the convention of putting constants to the left of `==` is to prevent programmer mistakes. It's called [Yoda conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) (I'll expand on this at the end of the answer).

You talk about performance, so I suggest you view the bytecode:

```
a == 0
```

becomes:

```
   5: iload_1       
   6: ifne          13
   9: iconst_1      
  10: goto          14
  13: iconst_0
```

and

```
0 == a
```

becomes:

```
  20: iload_1       
  21: ifne          28
  24: iconst_1      
  25: goto          29
  28: iconst_0
```

In other words, the two are absolutely identical at the bytecode level, so there can't be a performance difference between them.

So it really comes down to readability. The principal purpose of conditions of the form `int == var` is to avoid mistakes like `var = int` (notice the single `=`), which would not test for equality but rather *assign* to `var` and return the value of the assignment. The value of the assignment is an integer, which in many programming languages can be used in a boolean context. In Java, however, an integer *cannot* be used in a boolean context, so you don't need to worry about mistakenly typing a single-equal instead of a double-equal, since it will be flagged by the compiler as an error. Therefore, you should prefer `a == 0` in Java, and not the reverse which is slightly more convoluted and harder to read.

In fact, the Wikipedia article I linked to makes this statement:

> Critics of Yoda conditions see the lack of readability as a disadvantage that does not outweigh the benefits described above. Some programming languages do not allow variable assignments within conditionals, so this error is impossible to make.

Answer (score 1):

- In matters of speed `a == 0` and `0 == a` has the same speed.
- However people write 0 == a just not to mistake `==` with `=` because `a = 0` compiles in certain programming languages inside the if/while/.. statements and result incorrect behavior of the program

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a benchmark for the statement that `0==a` is faster than `a==0`. I just viewed the bytecode for two files that differed only in their use of their choice of whether the constant was at the left of right of the `==` and found no difference to the bytecode.

Many people choose to put the constant on the left side to ensure that an accidental use of the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==` gets caught by the compiler. It's less of an issue in Java since unless the value of `a` is a boolean this won't typecheck.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a constant on the left side of a comparison protects you against testing the result of an assignment (in C).

In java it is very much less likely, as

```
if (a = 0) {}
```

is not legal, a not being a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference but if you are working with string object like:

```
String s = null;

if(s.equals("yourValue")){
    // do something...
} else {
    // do other things...
}
```

will cause Exception while:

```
if("yourValue".equals(s)){
    // do something...
} else {
    // do other things...
}
```

this way will prevent the unnecessary Exceptions.

Comment: So it will prevent a fail-early exception and let you run into it later. :)

Comment: Instead of putting null and empty check before any optional operation you can do that using only single condition, but only if we look at positively. :)

Answer (score -1):

if(0==a){ … } is same as if(a==0){ … }. The code will always run when the set condition is true. It is only logical / psychological  to place variable value "a" before the constant "0". that is if(a==0){ … }.